why doesnt z-index doesnt work properly in Safari on iPhone?
I have a product card that when you click on it a modal should appear that is position: fixed; and it has a z-index: 1000;. But only on 1 specific page of Safari it doesn't work properly.
If you have a iPhone you can see it on the live website here (unless it has been fixed already):
Page that doesn't work ---
Page that does work
You can test it by clicking on a product card
On that page I did a test I have this code containing the product with the modal
      .productCardsContainerWrapper {
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;

        .productCardsContainer {
          display: flex;
          gap: 15px;

          width: fit-content;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;

          padding: 5px 8px;
        }
      }


I did one test where I removed this and it somewhat fixed the issue.
  overflow-x: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;

The problem is I actually need to have that that code because it needs to scroll horizontally
If you have a iPhone you can see it on the live website here (unless it has been fixed already):
Page that doesn't work ---
Page that does work
You can test it by clicking on a product card
Here is more code.
products.scss
.productModalContainer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0.99;

  .background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    z-index: 1000 !important;

    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }

  .productModal {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

    z-index: 1001 !important;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    height: 70vh;
    width: 85%;
    max-width: 420px;
    padding: 16px;

    border-top-left-radius: 24px;
    border-top-right-radius: 24px;

    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

    overflow-y: auto;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0px;
    }

    .closeText {
      position: absolute;
      top: -25px;
      right: 5px;

      z-index: 1001;

      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .productImgContainer {
      width: 100%;
      aspect-ratio: 1;

      .productImg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 8px;
      }
    }

    .productName {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 500;

      .productPackaging {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: gray;
      }
    }

    .productPrice {
      font-size: 24px;
      font-weight: 500;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .productSizeSelectContainer {
      margin: 20px 0px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;

      .productSizeSelect {
        border-radius: 8px;
        padding: 6px 16px;
        background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
      }
    }

    .buyBtn {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      text-align: center;

      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007396, #164c74);

      padding: 6px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      margin-bottom: 100px;

      text-decoration: none;

      .buyBtnText {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        gap: 0px 5px;
        width: 100%;

        .iconContainer {
          font-size: 26px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


HomePage.scss (the page that is broken)
.homePage {
  .productsSectionWrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

    .productsSection {
      margin-top: 20px;

      .sectionTitle {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: $sectionTitleSize;
        font-weight: $sectionTitleWeight;
      }

      .productCardsContainerWrapper {
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto !important;

        .productCardsContainer {
          display: flex;
          gap: 15px;

          width: fit-content;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;

          padding: 5px 8px;
        }
      }

      .viewAllProductsBtnContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 20px;

        .viewAllProductsBtn {
          text-align: center;

          background-color: $mainColor-1;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;

          padding: 8px 20px;
          border-radius: 5px;

          transition: 130ms;

          &:hover {
            background-color: $mainColor-1-hover;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

